# Laravel 4 eager loaded nested relation returned as array, I want Model

Tags: php, orm, laravel-4, eager-loading, relationships

I am having problems accessing an object retrieved from a nested relationship. I can only access the nested relation as an array (it is returned as json). The other relation is returned fine as a Model. (I'm totally new to Laravel 4 and a lot of its concepts btw).

So say I use, `$category = Category::with('publications.author')->find(5);` I can iterate over the publications using `$category->publications` and `$category->publications[0]->title` will return what I expect.

The problem I have is when trying to access `author`:

`$category->publications[0]->author->last_name` throws an exception - 'Trying to get property of non-object'

but:

`$category->publications[0]->author['last_name']` will return what I want.

This isn't a showstopper but I would like it to work as it looks like it should work according to the Laravel documentation.

So, where am I going wrong? Am I going about this the wrong way? Have I missed something? I have checked my method names and relations defined and it all looks correct to me.

These are my three Models: 'Category', 'Publication', 'Author'. Their relationships are defined as below:

**Category**

```
class Category extends \Eloquent {

protected $table = 'category';

public function publications()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Publication');
}

public function authors()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Publication', 'Author');
}

}
```

**Publication**

```
class Publication extends \Eloquent {

protected $table = 'publication';

    public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Author');
}

    public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
}
}
```

**Author**

```
class Author extends \Eloquent {

protected $table = 'author';

public function publications()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Publication');
}

}
```

I want to use the following code to get the data I want:

```
    $items = array();
    $category = Category::with('publications.author')->find(5);
    foreach($category->publications as $v)
    {
        $items[] = new ContentTeaser($v->title, $v->author->last_name, $v->slug, $v->default_image);
    }
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

Relation that return many result will be return as `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`, hence you can manipulate it as array. Please refer to [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations) under Dynamic Property subject for clarification.

The model that you are mentioning is actually an Object in PHP. Object does not have a key and cannot be treated as array, it will have a property. A collection of result will have a number of object returned from the relation if the relation is one to many or many to many.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out, and on reflection I don't think my question was particularly clear. The 'Trying to get property of non-object' error was happening when I was iterating over the collection and trying to access the 'author' properties (first_name, last_name) when there were some null results present for the author object.